# Searching lists using full text search with sqlite and python3

Tags: python, sqlite, full-text-search

I am using full text search to search through an sqlite database in python. The problem is that one of the columns in my database contains a string representation of a list. (ex: `['stuff', ' more stuff', 'more stuff]` ).

When I am performing full text search on that column and another column in my database, I need to convert the 'list' column into an actual list and then check the individual elements of the list with full text search. Is there a way to convert the string list into a list and then check the individual elements while performing the SELECT query?

(I am using fts5, sqlite3, python3)

Comment: Can you provide [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you are using?

Comment: I no longer need an answer to this question as I converted my database into a new database with a many to one relationship; I will leave the question up just in case it might be helpful to someone else in the future.